# why double register a service when use a factory function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was reading a book that show how Dependency Injection works when use factory function, below is the code:

```
//MemoryRepository implements IRepository

public class Startup
{
    private IHostingEnvironment env;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment hostEnv) => env = hostEnv;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IRepository>(provider =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var x = provider.GetService<MemoryRepository>();
                return x;
            }
            else
            {
                return new XXX();  //return sth else;
            }
        });
        services.AddTransient<MemoryRepository>();
        ...//register other components which are dependencies of MemoryRepository
        services.AddMvc();
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't know why `services.AddTransient<MemoryRepository>();` is needed?

Because `services.AddTransient<IRepository>{...}` already defined "Transient" scope, which means that "every time when an IRepository is needed, a new MemoryRepository objects will be provided (if it is development environment)", so everything is setup, the other dependencies of MemoryRepository will be handled by the following registrations.

Q1-So why we still need to have `services.AddTransient<MemoryRepository>();` again? if I comment it out, the application cannot run, so this statement is needed, I just don't know why

Q2- if I modify the configureServices as :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddTransient<IRepository, MemoryRepository>();
   ...
}
```

the application runs successfully, so why in the case, I don't need to add `services.AddTransient<MemoryRepository>();` as:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddTransient<IRepository, MemoryRepository>();
   services.AddTransient<MemoryRepository>();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository>(...
```

tells the provider what to do when asked to resolve `IRepository`

The second one

```
services.AddTransient<MemoryRepository>();
```

tells the provider what to do when asked to resolve `MemoryRepository`

You are technically not "double" registering.

> So why we still need to have `services.AddTransient<MemoryRepository>()`

So that when

```
provider.GetService<MemoryRepository>();
```

is invoked in the factory delegate the provider knows how to resolve it to satisfy the development environment condition.

The code sample is basically showing how to do a conditional dependency, which I think you already understood.

> Q2

In the second scenario there is no need for the second registration

```
services.AddTransient<MemoryRepository>();
```

because in that case the single implementation is all that was needed unless there is an explicit need to use the `MemoryRepository` as an injected dependency

Comment: I edited my post , could you have a look at the Q2, according to what you said, I need to have `services.AddTransient<MemoryRepository>()` , but I don't have it and the application still runs successfully.

Comment: why? isn't that  `services.AddTransient<IRepository, MemoryRepository>();` means when asked 'IRepository' provide a new MemoryRepository object, isn't that the provider still need to be instructed what to do when asked to resolve MemoryRepository?

Comment: Only if you need to explicitly use the `MemoryRepository` as an injected dependency

Comment: so do you mean `services.AddTransient<XXX, YYY>(); ` is a wrapper function for `services.AddTransient<XXX>(provider =>...`? asp.net core does things behind the scene?

Comment: In a way, yes. That could be a way of looking at it